# Add row values of all columns when a particular column value is null until it gets the not null values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
df
col1      col2      col3      col4
 A         12        34        XX
 B         20        25        PP
 B         nan       nan       nan
 nan       P         54        nan
 nan       R         nan       nan
 nan       nan       nan       PQ
  C         D         32       SS
  R         S         32       RS
```

If col1 value is null I want to add all the values of other columns untill it finds the notnull element in col1

The data frame i am looking for should look like:

```
col1     col2     col3     col4
 A         12       34       XX
 B         20       25       PP
 B         PR       54       PQ
 C          D       32       SS
 R          S       32       RS
```

How to do in in most efficient way using python/pandas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If want processes all columns like strings first forward filling missing values in `col1`, replace `NaN`s to empty strings, convert all values to `strings` and use `sum`:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].ffill()
df = df.set_index('col1').fillna('').astype(str).sum(level=0).reset_index()
print (df)
  col1 col2  col3 col4
0    A   12  34.0   XX
1    B   PR  54.0   PQ
2    C    D  32.0   SS

print (df.dtypes)
col1     object
col2     object
col3     object
col4     object
dtype: object
```

If need processes only numeric columns with aggregate method, e.g. `mean` use lambda function with `if-else`:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].ffill()
c = df.select_dtypes(object).columns
df[c] = df[c].fillna('')

f = lambda x: x.mean() if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else ''.join(x)
df = df.groupby('col1').agg(f).reset_index()
print (df)
  col1 col2  col3 col4
0    A   12  34.0   XX
1    B   PR  54.0   PQ
2    C    D  32.0   SS

print (df.dtypes)
col1     object
col2     object
col3    float64
col4     object
dtype: object
```

EDIT: New helper column is used:

```
df['new'] = df['col1'].notna().cumsum()
df['col1'] = df['col1'].ffill()
c = df.select_dtypes(object).columns
df[c] = df[c].fillna('')

f = lambda x: x.mean() if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else ''.join(x)
df = df.groupby(['col1', 'new']).agg(f).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
```

Comment: If the col1 is duplicate its concatenating horizontally. How to handle it ?

Comment: @KallolSamanta - Not sure if understand, do you need `df['col1'] = df['col1'].ffill()
df.index = df['col1'].ne(df['col1'].shift()).cumsum()
df = df.fillna('').astype(str).sum(level=0).reset_index()` ?

Comment: example is edited, please have a look into the question again

Comment: second solution